# tikzpicture - edges in matrix row not aligned | bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Fairly simple problem. In the following MWE, I am trying to draw 2 nodes in a graph, with edges between each of the nodes, and one entering the first labeled node, and one leaving the final labeled node. To generate the entering and leaving edge, I create 2 empty elements in the matrix (one at each end). While it all works, if you look at the following image,

[image]

the first edge entering node (1), the edge connecting (1) and (2), and the final edge leaving node (2), are NOT aligned. It looks (to me, and a few others I asked) that the edge entering/leaving the graph are slightly 'sloped'.

Bug? Or am I missing something... (perhaps there is a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do).

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning,fit}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,transform canvas={scale=1.05},line 
 width=1.0pt]
 \matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=7em, every node/.style= 
 {circle,draw,font=\small\sffamily,minimum width=1.25cm},
 n.node/.style={font=\bf\small\sffamily},
 empty.node/.style={draw=none,minimum width=1.5cm}]
 { |[empty.node]| & [-2em]|[n.node]|$N_1$  & |[n.node]|$N_2$ & [-2em]|[empty.node]|\\};]
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge  (a-1-3);
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge (a-1-2) ;
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge (a-1-4) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

No bug I think, you've missed this:

[image]

If you add `anchor=center` to the `every node` style the alignment is correct.

Comment: Documentation? We don't need no stinking documentation. ;-) Seriously, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Torbjørn T. indicated, `anchor=center` fixes things. For comparison, here is the same image using `tikz-cd` instead of `matrix`, which has somewhat simpler code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw, line width=1pt, circle, minimum size=1.25cm, anchor=center}}, 
    column sep=7em, arrows={line width=1pt, >=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt}]
|[draw=none]|\arrow[r] &[-2em] N_1\arrow[r] & N_2\arrow[r] &[-2em] |[draw=none]|
\end{tikzcd}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed -- I thought about tikz-cd, but I have so much legacy 'investment' in the tikzpicture-matrix approach that at this point, I'm loathe to introduce a new approach. But, by the end of the academic year, I might have a long(er) look at tikz-cd. Thanks!